# Is it possible to list the actual commands that have been scheduled with `at`?

Tags: cron, schedule

I'd like to be able to see exactly what has been scheduled with `at`.  `atq` will list the job id, time to run, and user to run as, but not the actual task that will be run.

Thanks!

**Edit** I should add that I'm running on a VPS, so solutions that require a GUI won't work for me.

Comment: Probably: `at -c <job-number>`?

Comment: @Rinzwind : This appears to do what I want it to do. I'm surprised I over-looked it.  Thanks!  **BTW**  You should submit an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: cool. was not sure since did not have a terminal present.Making answer now :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line command you are looking for is

```
at -c <job-number1> <job-number2> <job-number3>
```

This will show what you need for 1 job. You can add more job-numbers behind each other separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: [gnome-schedule [image: Install gnome-schedule]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-schedule).

To install it using terminal run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

It's a GUI version of task/cron management list which you can create and manage.

Comment: Does this facilitate listing commands that have *already* been scheduled with the `at` command?